# Is [linguistics] a duplicate of [language]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) tag with 46 questions, and also [linguistics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) with 2 questions. The tags have identical descriptions, so I think they should be synonyms. Is there any difference between these two tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that these tags have identical tag wikis, I've synonymized them.

[linguistics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) is now -> [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)